# What does the tag <# mean?

Tags: javascript, tags

Any body know What does this tag means `<# #>` in script ?
Please check the Image below attached for view detail

[image]

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: looks like some server side pre-processor that I've never seen before - any info about the server would help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This notation is used for templates in the source code of [Kirki](http://kirki.org/), a Wordpress tool. You might be familiar with other template tag variations such as `<% %>` (Rails).

I assume that the snippet from your image is taken from [this file](https://github.com/aristath/kirki/blob/b2117547b823080584a92043d93fc1b9ca9260c3/includes/controls/class-kirki-controls-repeater-control.php#L105).